# Por razones de seguridad, la DTD está prohibida en este documento XML. error de compilacion xslt

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

por que motivo no logro realizar la transformacion de mi documento xml con un xslt? siempre me lanza esta excepcion "Por razones de seguridad, la DTD está prohibida en este documento XML.
Para habilitar el procesamiento de la DTD, establezca la propiedad DtdProcessing
de XmlReaderSettings en Parse y pase la configuración al método XmlReader.Create." pese haberlo realizado sigue marcando el mismo error , investigando sobre la dtd , tengo entendido que es un documento en el cual se define la estructuracion de un documento xml , pero yo no tengo definido ningun dtd por que motivos puede pasar esto y como puedo realizar la transformacion de un xml mediante un xslt ? adjunto codigo:

okey en primer lugar, yo genero en mi codigo dinamicamente las etiquetas XML con un objeto de la clase  "XmlDocument" y aqui lo salvo en un path lo cual si hace:

```
DocumentoAlerta.Save(PathCompleto);
```

cabe destacar que "DocumentoAlerta" es el objeto que genera las etiquetas xml , ahora el problema viene aca , en un string en mi maquina local , yo pongo el path completo de donde tengo yo guardado mi xslt  un ejemplo :

```
string RutaXSLT = "aqui va la ruta completa del xslt";
```

ahora , compruebo si existe:

```
    if (File.Exists(PathCompletoXslt)){   
       //si encuentra el path del xslt , por lo tanto entra en el if 
       //pongo la propiedad DtdProcessing en parse para poder permitir la validacion del dtd
       XmlReaderSettings configuracion = new XmlReaderSettings();
       configuracion.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
       using (XmlReader LectorXML = XmlReader.Create(PathCompleto, configuracion))
                        {
                            XslCompiledTransform XslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
                            XslTransform.Load(PathCompletoXslt);

                            using (TextWriter ArchivoAlertaHTML = new StreamWriter("ruta donde se ira el resultado del xslt ejemplo index.html"))
                            {
                                XslTransform.Transform(LectorXML, null, ArchivoAlertaHTML);
                            }
                        }
}
```

el problema viene al intentar cargar el documento xslt , y un dato que tengo que agregar , yo no tengo ningun dtd declarado no logro comprender por que me siguen diciendo que hay un error al intentar procesar el dtd

Comment: pero con que necesidad usas una dtd? si lo generas vos, sabes la estructura... todo el resto sobra...

Comment: ¿Tiene el XSLT tambien un DOCTYPE? En este caso tienes que utilizar un XmlReader con XmlReaderSettings de DtdProcessing.Parse tambien con XslTransform.Load.